# Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'dnnConfirm'

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I have this vTicker jQuery It work properly on my local system but when i upload it to the server it start giving me this error :

**Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'dnnConfirm'**

this is my aspx page where i m calling:

```
script type="text/javascript" src="/Resources/Shared/scripts/jquery/jquery.vticker.js"

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

        $('#news-container').vTicker({

            speed: 500,
            pause: 4000,
            animation: 'fade',
            mousePause: true,
            showItems: 5
        });
    });
</script>
```

I have used jQuery sign instead of $ sign but no use.

here i sthe link plz chk
http://www.himpakistan.pk/test1.aspx

Comment: What is the order of scripts you icluded